# Is there any difference between dw and daw in Vim?

Tags: vim

When I delete a word, I use <kbd>dw</kbd>, but I found out that there is <kbd>daw</kbd>, which can be memorized as “delete a word”.

Is there any difference between <kbd>dw</kbd> and <kbd>daw</kbd>?

Comment: Move your cursor to the middle of the word and try both of them.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html):

> For example, compare "dw" and "daw": "dw"
>   deletes from the cursor position to the start of the next word, "daw" deletes
>   the word under the cursor and the space after or before it.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that `aw` is an example of an object selection: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#object-select

Answer (score 8):

:h daw

you will see more information.

"dw" deletes from the cursor position but the "daw" deletes the word under the cursor.

"daW" delete a WORD

:h word

A word consists of a sequence of letters, digits and underscores, or a
sequence of other non-blank characters, separated with white space (spaces,
tabs, ).  This can be changed with the 'iskeyword' option.  An empty line
is also considered to be a word.

:h WORD

A WORD consists of a sequence of non-blank characters, separated with white
space.  An empty line is also considered to be a WORD.

Comment: `daW` would delete a WORD; `daw` deletes a word.